# How to show right-click context menu in WebView of Android app on Chromebook

Tags: android, android-webview, chromebook

I'm developing an Android app that has a `WebView` which shows various content. When I long-click with my finger (touch for a longer time) some text, a standard (horizontal) Android context menu popups up. However when I right-click with the mouse or touchpad in the same `WebView` no context menu is shown - and it doesn't matter if some text is selected or not.

I've tried looking through a lot of solutions, and even the the callback brought to [`setOnContextClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setOnContextClickListener(android.view.View.OnContextClickListener)) (as shown [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/input-compatibility#right-click_support)) isn't called when right-clicking (however the generic motion event callbacks are called), so it seems like it's not supported at all in WebViews.

In the end it seems like I would have to create my own context menu. I'm just wondering if there isn't any standard one that just has to be enabled in some way.

What I would like to have is something similar to the `EditText` right-click context menu which is vertical, but I haven't been able to show either of the two when right-clicking. Both horizontal and vertical menus are shown [here](https://chromeunboxed.com/news/default-right-click-context-menus-android-apps-chromebooks/).

I'm testing on a HP Chromebook x360 11 G1 EE if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can `override` the `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` in the `WebView` and detect the `event.getButtonState()` to see which button was clicked.

```
    switch (event.getButtonState()) {
        case MotionEvent.BUTTON_PRIMARY:
            onMouseClickListener.onLeftClick();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.BUTTON_SECONDARY:
            onMouseClickListener.onRightClick();
            break;
    }
```

Please note that the `onMouseClickListener` is a custom listener for this event.